# WpfAninatedGif NuGet package event usage with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've encountered a problem with events using WpfAnimatedGif NuGet package. Package has two additional events for `<image>` but I'm unable to use them with MVVM pattern. I've tried interactivity:

```
<Window 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com">

    <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="animation.gif">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="AnimationCompleted">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Image>
</Window>
```

but it fails, command doesn't get called. I've messed around a bit and got it kinda working (not realy). If I leave `EventTrigger`'s `EventName` unspecified command does get called but on `AnimationLoaded` event only:

```
<i:EventTrigger>
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

In this situation command is called properly. However, I'm interested in `AnimationCompleted` event.

P.S. Everything works fine without MVVM.

Comment: No idea, but have you thought about inspecting it at runtime using Snoop?  Might help isolate issues you didn't realize you had...

Comment: Unable to get snoop to work. There are some mayor localization problems  (parser throws exception when parsing string "0" to Int32, saying that 0 is not a valid value for Int32. Same happens for any other digit). ;(

Comment: Used _Xaml Spy_ instead. Nothing out of the ordinary was found.

Comment: If you can create a minimal reproable project, open a connect with microsoft. It might be a bug, if you can't find anything wrong with the bindings at runtime.